# Get the data from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two tables user and group.

```
user      group
-----    ------- 
id        id   
name      group_name
          created_by
```

In my user model I have used , `has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, dependent: :destroy`

In my group model I have used, `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, dependent: :destroy`

I have create a migration

```
class UserGameGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_game_group, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

So in my group controller`s show method, I want to fetch users for specific group.
Suppose if I am currently on group 4, I want to fetch all the users based on that group.

I can do this `Group.where(group_id: 4)` but it will only give me the id of the user. Is there a way to get the name of the user too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose if I am currently on group 4, I want to fetch all the users based on that group

```
@group = Group.find 4
@group.users.each do |user| #-> collection of User objects for @group
  user.name
end
```

---

Your join table name is wrong.

For `has_and_belongs_to_many`, it should be [`[alphabetical_first_plural]_[alphabetical_second_plural]`](http://ruby-journal.com/rails-4-changes-join-table-naming-convention/), in your case `groups_users`:

```
class UserGameGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

If you wanted to use the table name you have, you'd have to explicitly define the `join_table`option in your model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, join_table: :user_game_groups
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :user_game_groups
end
```

---

To populate the join table, you can use the [`<<` & `.delete` methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Association+Join+Models):

```
@user  = User.find x
@group = Group.find y

@user.groups << @group
@user.groups.delete @group
```

Comment: my user_game_groups table is empty so when I used you code I got empty array, however I have data in my user as well as group table. why am I getting empty response? So I checked my db and I cant add anything to the user_game_groups table

Answer (score 1):

In your current example you're querying for a single group which will have the method `users` on it. So likewise you could use this call to retrieve a collection of user records.

```
group = Group.where(group_id: 4)
group.users  # Returns a collection of users.
```

If you want to make a single query you can use `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` `include` method like so.

```
Group.includes(:user).where(group_id: 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your joining group to `groups_users`. Rails expect the joining group to be in this format (smaller alphabet of the joining tables first and table named separated by `_`). plus both should be plural. Also both your table names group and user should be plural such as `groups` and `users` otherwise you have to specify the table name manually on the model.

Moreover, in order to fetch the name and other attributes for user, you can do something like

```
 group = Group.find(4)    
 group_users = group.users
```

`group_users` will give you the list of all the users that belong to group with id 4.